# Secure way to use API keys and Client Secrets in the frontend of a django app

Tags: reactjs, django, environment-variables

I have a django application with a react frontend. The frontend connects to a websocket server at one point with the following code `client.send('PASS ${password}');`. What is a safe secure way to keep that password in the backend and then access it when I need to connect to the websocket.

Currently I just have it set as an environment variable and use an api request to my REST API to retrieve it when I want to connect. This works but I feel like its not the best way to do this.

Comment: The flow of your application is quite unclear. The frontend (your React application) is what the user interacts with. The whole point of a password is that it's something only the user knows and which they provides to your server to authenticate themselves, using your frontend application. It shouldn't be stored anywhere, instead, it should be checked by the server, then a session token returned (cookie) which is then stored by the client (browser) and sent along within every future request. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/auth/ for more information on how Django does this.

Comment: Oh sorry that’s my bad. Could have worded better. That’s an api key not a user determined password.